# Use of Service Agents while calling web Service

Tags: web-services, design-patterns

Can any one explain the use of service agent while calling web service? how it fit in project architecture?

Answer (score 2):

In MVC a.k.a. Model View Controller,

```
View -> Controller -> Service Agent
```

Service Agent acts like proxy to the web service. It can sit at resource access layer in your application.

- Controller initializes a call to the
  service agent because the view
  requires some data or needs to
  perform some operations from the
  services.
- After controller gets the result from
  the agent, it performs some logic and
  applies the **Model** to the view.

EDIT:

The agent wraps proxy classes so that it will take care of the instancing of the proxies and handling the errors from the server etc. Proxy classes are the generic interfaces to the web service and agents have more logic implemented for the services related. E.g. you can translate the response into Model and return it to the Controller.

Comment: So how does a Service Agent differ from the web service proxy classes we've been using for years, and why do they deserve their own name ("service agent")?

Comment: providing extra service agent layer sound great to hide service protocol details and service type from controller. Also to pass security token and prepare service request object, I am considering to fit service agent in-between.